# Дважды одна и та же запись

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте, возникла потребность выбрать из базы массив который содержит одни и те же записи...например в базе у меня есть таблица с пользователями...допустим их два...у первого id = 1, а у второго id = 2 соответственно. Ещё есть таблица с постами...их пусть будет 3. У каждого поста есть поле которое хранит в себе id пользователя который опубликовал этот пост. Таким образом, если выбирать из базы пользователей для того что бы прикрутить данные пользователя к посту...то возникает проблема! Если один и тот же пользователь опубликовал 2 поста, то выборка из базы не выбирает одну и ту же строку дважды...вопрос в том: как выбрать одного и того же пользователя дважды...
Вот не рабочий код `$sql = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (1,1,2)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему так: $sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` JOIN `post` ON `users`.`id`=`post`.`id_sender` WHERE `post`.`id_accept` = '$id' ORDER BY `post`.`id` DESC"; если делать циклом то очень много запросов...так что методом цикла...это очень сильно нагружает систему...а так вместо 20 запросов...получается всего один) круто, не правда ли? =)

Comment: Молодец что разобрался! Держи +.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно в таком случае циклами (`while`) воспользоваться и не надо делать `id IN (1,1,2)` а нужно просто `id IN (1,2)`:

Comment: Какие циклы!? 1 запрос SQL!